# How to run an app developed in CoffeeScript on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a Node.js app developed in CoffeeScript onto Cloud Foundry. Is there a buildpack that will compile my code into JavaScript when I push my app?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no Cloud Foundry buildpack that compiles CoffeeScript into JS. What I recommend using is a tool like [jbuild](https://github.com/pmuellr/jbuild) to create a script that compiles your code and pushes it to Cloud Foundry in one simple command. You can use this [sample CF app](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/todo-apps/tree/master/node) built in CoffeeScript that takes advantage of this tool as reference.